# Column by column product: matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, matrix

I have a matrix `A`  in MATLAB and a vector of integers `B`. I then construct a matrix `D` by deleting the columns of `A` indexed by the same integer in `B` and replacing them with one column of zero. I have a question regarding the code I use to construct `D` as it does seem to work in MATLAB R2017b but not in MATLAB R2015b.

Let me explain better with an example:

```
b=8;
g=3;

B=[1;2;2;2;3;4;4;5]; %bx1
bnew=size(unique(B),1);

A=[1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8;
   9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16;
   17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]; %gxb
```

The matrix `B` tells us which columns of `A` should be deleted and replaced with a column of zeros. For example: the second, the third, and the fourth element of `B` are equal; this means that the second, the third, and the fourth columns of `A` should be deleted and one column of zeros should be added.

Hence,

```
D=[1  0  5   0  8;
   9  0  13  0  16;
   17 0  21  0  24]; %gxbnew
```

To construct `D` I do as follows:

```
C=sparse(1:numel(B),B,1); 
E = A * C;
D= E .* (sum(C) <= 1);
```

Notice: it is important to treat `C,E,D` as sparse because in my actual case they are very big. In this respect, one may e.g. think about getting `D` by doing

```
C=sparse(1:numel(B),B,1); 
D = E;
D(:, sum(C) > 1) = 0;
```

but I don't want this as it is incredibly slower.

---

**Question:** When I run

```
C=sparse(1:numel(B),B,1); 
E = A * C;
D= E .* (sum(C) <= 1);
```

in MATLAB R2017b it works perfectly, but when I run it  in MATLAB R2015b, it doesn't like the last line and gives as error

```
Error using .*
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

How can I solve this preserving efficiency?

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan. Any idea on how to fix this for Matlab_R2015b without loosing speed?

Comment: [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code relies on broadcasting/implicit expansion in R2017b, something which was introduced.In R2016b. If you try broadcasting in older versions, you'll get dimension errors. That's why `[1 2] + [1;2]` errors in pre-R2016b, but works in later versions and gives a 2-by-2 matrix. The solution is, as [Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664578/column-by-column-product-in-matlab-matrix-dimensions-must-agree?noredirect=1#comment92259739_52664578) commented to use [`bsxfun`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which stands for *Binary Singleton eXpansion FUNction*, meaning that it does the same as the implicit expansion which is now enabled by default.

```
A = [1 2]; % 1x2
B = [3;4]; % 2x1
C = B*A; % 2x2 matrix in post-R2016b, dimension error in pre-R2016b
D = bsxfun(@times,B,A); % Working pre-R2016b
```

If you want your code working on both versions, use `bsxfun`, or alternatively wrap it in a `try/catch` block:

```
try % try implicit expansion
    C = B*A;
catch % if that fails, use bsxfun
    C = bsxfun(@times,B,A);
end
```

Citing the `bsxfun` documentation:

> In MATLAB® R2016b and later, the built-in binary functions listed in this table independently support implicit expansion. With these functions, you can call the function or operator directly instead of using `bsxfun`. For example, you can replace `C = bsxfun(@plus,A,B)` with `A+B`.